# Python list.clear complexity

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-complexity

What is the complexity of the Python 3 method `list.clear()` ?

- **It is not given here:** https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity
- In the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html) it is said to be equivalent with `del
  a[:]`, but I do not know the complexity of this function itself. Is
  it `O(n)` or `O(1)` ?
- I took a look in `listobject.c`. Found this.

  ```
  int
  PyList_ClearFreeList(void)
  {
      PyListObject *op;
      int ret = numfree;
      while (numfree) {
          op = free_list[--numfree];
          assert(PyList_CheckExact(op));
          PyObject_GC_Del(op);
      }
      return ret;
  }
  ```

  Here it seems like `O(n)`, but I am not sure if this is the right code.

I am developing a program with **performance** needs, where a list is repeatedly filled and emptied, I am trying to find the best way to empty it (Since there is only one way to fill it).

If this function is `O(n)`, I will just **create a new list every time**, which has it's own cost, but I don't know a better way.

Another issue crossed my mind is that Python has a garbage collector, so if I don't free these objects(create new lists every time, leaving the other unattended by reassigning the variable name), Python does the deletion in the background(I am not sure about this information), so I won't gain speed applying any of the methods above because result is the same.

Any knowledge is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The function that you found is not related to `list.clear()` in Python. What you need is `_list_clear(PyListObject *a)`, and it can be found [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8d62df60d8733d0fa9aee14ef746d0009a7a9726/Objects/listobject.c#L600).

So, if you look into an implementation of that method, it looks as follows:

```c
...
static int
_list_clear(PyListObject *a)
{
    Py_ssize_t i;
    PyObject **item = a->ob_item;
    if (item != NULL) {
        /* Because XDECREF can recursively invoke operations on
           this list, we make it empty first. */
        i = Py_SIZE(a);
        Py_SIZE(a) = 0;
        a->ob_item = NULL;
        a->allocated = 0;
        while (--i >= 0) {
            Py_XDECREF(item[i]);
        }
        PyMem_FREE(item);
    }
    /* Never fails; the return value can be ignored.
       Note that there is no guarantee that the list is actually empty
       at this point, because XDECREF may have populated it again! */
    return 0;
}
...
```

However, the most important lines are one, in which you're retrieving a size of a list:

```
i = Py_SIZE(a);
```

And ones, in which you're removing an element:

```
...
    while (--i >= 0) {
        Py_XDECREF(item[i]);
    }
...
```

As performance of `Py_XDECREF` doesn't depend on the size of the list, we can consider it constant or O(1). Since `Py_XDECREF` is called size of list times, the overall time complexity is linear and so the time complexity of `_list_clear` is O(n).

As pointed out by @superb rain, `Py_XDECREF` may turn quite "heavy" for some elements (due to possible recursive calls), and although it's not directly related to the input size, we can account for this by introducing a parameter `e` - the total cost of decreasing the reference counts of the elements. In this interpretation, the total time complexity is O(n+e).