# Python list.clear() time and space complexity?

Tags: python, time-complexity, cpython, space-complexity

I am writing a blogpost on Python `list.clear()` method where I also want to mention about the time and space complexity of the underlying algorithm. I expected the time complexity to be **O(N)**, iterate over the elements and free the memory? But, I found an [article](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Ebrgallar/week8_2.html) where it is mentioned that it is actually an **O(1)** operation. Then, I searched the source code of the method in CPython implementation and found a method which I believe is the actual internal implementation of `list.clear()`, however, I am not really sure it is. Here's the source code of the method:

```c
static int
_list_clear(PyListObject *a)
{
    Py_ssize_t i;
    PyObject **item = a->ob_item;
    if (item != NULL) {
        /* Because XDECREF can recursively invoke operations on
          this list, we make it empty first. */
        i = Py_SIZE(a);
        Py_SIZE(a) = 0;
        a->ob_item = NULL;
        a->allocated = 0;
        while (--i >= 0) {
           Py_XDECREF(item[i]);
        }
        PyMem_FREE(item);
    }
    /* Never fails; the return value can be ignored.
       Note that there is no guarantee that the list is actually empty
       at this point, because XDECREF may have populated it again! */
    return 0;
}
```

I could be wrong but it does look like **O(N)** to me. Also, I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46985483/python-list-clear-complexity), but there's no clear answer there. Just want to confirm the actual **time and space complexity** of `list.clear()`, and maybe a little explanation supporting the answer. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What happened when you used the [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) module to time the clear method for a list with say ten thousand items and one with ten million items?

Comment: @wwii It is impossible to time `list.clear` using `timeit` because `timeit` runs many iterations of the code, and `list.clear` clears the list, so the next iterations will work on the empty list. If you attempt to fix this by creating a new list in each iteration, you are confounding the measurement because list creation is definitely O(n).

Comment: The way to directly observe the complexity of `list.clear` it is to measure the time (with as precise a clock as you can get) of **one** execution of `list.clear` on lists with sizes of a thousand elements, then ten thousand, hundred thousand, million, etc. With a sufficient amount elements, the time will become measurable, and the linearity show.

Comment: @user4815162342 - well you would just have to tell timeit to perform one *loop*. - it should give sufficient results.

Comment: @wwii Sure, that would work as well, it's just that one needs to be careful not to use the default settings (which are quite reasonable in most scenarios).

Comment: So it is not: `impossible to time list.clear using timeit `

Comment: It's curious - that method is not listed in https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you correctly noticed, the **CPython** implementation of `list.clear` is O(n). The [code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8d62df60d8733d0fa9aee14ef746d0009a7a9726/Objects/listobject.c#L611) iterates over the elements in order to decrease the reference count of each one, without a way to avoid it. There is no doubt that it is an O(n) operation and, given a large enough list, you can measure the time spent in `clear()` as function of list size:

```py
import time

for size in 1_000_000, 10_000_000, 100_000_000, 1_000_000_000:
    l = [None] * size
    t0 = time.time()
    l.clear()
    t1 = time.time()
    print(size, t1 - t0)
```

The output shows linear complexity; on my system with Python 3.7 it prints the following:

```
1000000 0.0023756027221679688
10000000 0.02452826499938965
100000000 0.23625731468200684
1000000000 2.31496524810791
```

The time per element is of course tiny because the loop is coded in C and each iteration does very little work. But, as the above measurement shows, even a miniscule per-element factor eventually adds up. Small per-element constant is not the reason to ignore the cost of an operation, or the same would apply to the [loop](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8d62df60d8733d0fa9aee14ef746d0009a7a9726/Objects/listobject.c#L311) that shifts the list elements in `l.insert(0, ...)`, which is also very efficient - and yet few would claim insertion at the beginning to be O(1). (And `clear` potentially does *more* work because a decref will run an arbitrary chain of destructors for an object whose reference count actually reaches zero.)

On a philosophical level, one could argue that costs of memory management should be ignored when assessing complexity because otherwise it would be impossible to analyze anything with certainty, as any operation could trigger a GC. This argument has merit; GC does come occasionally and unpredictably, and its cost can be considered amortized across all allocations. In a similar vein complexity analysis tends to ignore the complexity of `malloc` because the parameters it depends on (like memory fragmentation) are typically not directly related to allocation size or even to the number of already allocated blocks. However, in case of `list.clear` there is only one allocated block, no GC is triggered, and the code is still visiting each and every list element. Even with the assumption of O(1) malloc and amortized O(1) GC, `list.clear` *still* takes the time proportional to the number of elements in the list.

The article linked from the question is about Python the language and doesn't mention a particular implementation. Python implementations that don't use reference counting, such as Jython or PyPy, are likely to have true O(1) `list.clear`, and for them the claim from the article would be entirely correct. So, when explaining the Python list on a conceptual level, it is not wrong to say that clearing the list is O(1) - after all, all the object references are in a contiguous array, and you free it only once. This is the point your blog post probably should make, and that is what the linked article is trying to say. Taking the cost of reference counting into account too early might confuse your readers and give them completely wrong ideas about Python's lists (e.g. they could imagine that they are implemented as linked lists).

Finally, at some point one must accept that memory management strategy does change complexity of *some* operations. For example, destroying a linked list in C++ is O(n) from the perspective of the caller; discarding it in Java or Go would be O(1). And not in the trivial sense of a garbage-collected language just postponing the same work for later - it is quite possible that a moving collector will only traverse reachable objects and will indeed never visit the elements of the discarded linked list. Reference counting makes discarding large containers algorithmically similar to manual collection, and GC can remove that. While CPython's `list.clear` has to touch every element to avoid a memory leak, it is quite possible that PyPy's garbage collector *never* needs to do anything of the sort, and thus has a true O(1) `list.clear`.

Comment: Thanks, pretty nicely written answer. I don't claim that I understood it 100%, but that's because of my limitation of knowledge. Thanks so much for your input.

Answer (score 4):

It's O(1) neglecting memory management. It's not quite right to say it's O(N) accounting for memory management, because accounting for memory management is complicated.

Most of the time, for most purposes, we treat the costs of memory management separately from the costs of the operations that triggered it. Otherwise, just about everything you could possibly do becomes O(who even knows), because almost any operation could trigger a garbage collection pass or an expensive destructor or something. Heck, even in languages like C with "manual" memory management, there's no guarantee that any particular `malloc` or `free` call will be fast.

There's an argument to be made that refcounting operations should be treated differently. After all, `list.clear` explicitly performs a number of `Py_XDECREF` operations equal to the list's length, and even if no objects are deallocated or finalized as a result, the refcounting itself will necessarily take time proportional to the length of the list.

If you count the `Py_XDECREF` operations `list.clear` performs explicitly, but ignore any destructors or other code that might be triggered by the refcounting operations, and you assume `PyMem_FREE` is constant time, then `list.clear` is O(N), where N is the original length of the list. If you discount all memory management overhead, including the explicit `Py_XDECREF` operations, `list.clear` is O(1). If you count all memory management costs, then the runtime of `list.clear` cannot be asymptotically bounded by any function of the list's length.

Answer (score 2):

As the other answers have noted, it takes O(*n*) time to clear a list of length *n*. But I think there is an additional point to be made about [amortized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis) complexity here.

If you start with an empty list, and do *N* `append` or `clear` operations in any order, then the total running time across all of those operations is always O(*N*), giving an average per operation of O(1), however long the list gets in the process, and however many of those operations are `clear`.

Like `clear`, the worst case for `append` is also O(*n*) time where *n* is the length of the list. That's because when the capacity of the underlying array needs to be increased, we have to allocate a new array and copy everything across. But the cost of copying each element can be "charged" to one of the `append` operations which got the list to a length where the array needs to be resized, in such a way that *N* `append` operations starting from an empty list always take O(*N*) time.

Likewise, the cost of decrementing an element's refcount in the `clear` method can be "charged" to the `append` operation which inserted that element in the first place, because each element can only get cleared once. The conclusion is that if you are using a list as an internal data structure in your algorithm, and your algorithm repeatedly clears that list inside a loop, then for the purpose of analysing your algorithm's time complexity you should count `clear` on that list as an O(1) operation, just as you'd count `append` as an O(1) operation in the same circumstances.

Comment: This answer makes an excellent and relevant point which was entirely missed by other responses, including my own. While it's true that `clear` is O(n), the nature of what it does guarantees that it can never accumulate into O(n^2), at least not on its own. This is because you cannot clear the same list n times - all clears other than the first will be O(1), unless you re-populate the list prior to every `clear`, but then the re-population is itself O(n), so O(n^2) complexity was not introduced by `clear`.

Answer (score -1):

A quick `time` check indicates that it is **O(n)**.

Let's execute the following and create the lists beforehand to avoid overhead:

```
import time
import random

list_1000000 = [random.randint(0,10) for i in range(1000000)]
list_10000000 = [random.randint(0,10) for i in range(10000000)]
list_100000000 = [random.randint(0,10) for i in range(100000000)]
```

Now check for the time it takes to clear these four lists of different sizes as follows:

```
start = time.time()
list.clear(my_list)
end = time.time()
print(end - start))
```

Results:

```
list.clear(list_1000000) takes 0.015
list.clear(list_10000000) takes 0.074
list.clear(list_100000000) takes 0.64
```

A more robust time measurement is needed, since these numbers can deviate each time it is ran, but the results indicate that the execution time goes pretty much linearly as the input size grows. Hence we can conclude an O(n) complexity.

Comment: @user4815162342 Doesn't going from a list of 1 to a million with 0 change in execution time clearly indicate a constant complexity? I mean, wasn't is supposed to move at least a tiny bit if it was not constant?

Comment: @user4815162342 Actually you are right - I'll edit my answer.